# Get id or email of employer from from payment retrive

Tags: square-connect

Is there a way to get Employee ID or email from payment retrive ?
Main goal is know which employer sold product via API.

Answer (score 0):

[`Payment`](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#datatype-payment) objects returned by the Connect API do not currently include the merchant-defined ID or email address of the mobile staff member that accepted the payment. They do include a `creator_id` field, which corresponds to a particular mobile staff member. If you can use other payment details to determine which `creator_id` maps to which mobile staff member, you can maintain a one-to-one mapping between them.

I've communicated this limitation to the Square Connect engineering team.